# How can I redirect to a new page after submitting a form using Jinja template?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm working my way through Google's App Engine Guestbook example (to be found here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/creating-guestbook)

I'm trying to redirect the output (the Greetings) to another page as opposed to the index.html where they're currently displayed after a user presses the "Sign the Guestbook" button. I created a separate page called greetings.html where I copied the display code from the index.html page. However, I don't know how to modify guestbook.py to make the output go to the new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webapp2 has a built-in `redirect` method:

`return redirect('/some-path')`

However, I think you would probably rather send the gathered data to the `greetings.html` template?  Under the `POST` method, you could do:

```
template_values = {
    'guestbook_name': guestbook_name,
    # etc.,
}

template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('greetings.html')
self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm not sure I know how to incorporate this. Can you please be more specific to the application at hand? Would I incorporate that in the post method under the class Guestbook? If so, how?